Search and filter with multiple tables
I want to search and filter from multiple tables with search term as input from user
I have tables like
Profiles
id      first_name  last_name   middle_name gender  life_status lds_number  status
1       Gilbert     Joy         Santos      Male    Living      987456      active
2       swati       santos      Anand       Female  Deceased    777888      active
3       Chirag      Satya       Kirad       Male    Living      111222      active

Vital
id  profile_id  birth_location  death_location  cause_death ethnicity
1   1           Usa                                         Asian
2   1           Canada                          ABCd        American
3   3           India                                       Indian

User can input multiple search term as living, santos
My output query is below for above search term
select * 
from profiles p
left join vital v on v.profile_id = p.id
where 
    (first_name like '%living%' 
     or middle_name like '%living%' 
     or gender like '%living%' 
     or life_status like '%living%' 
     or lds_number like '%living%')
    and (first_name like '%santos%' 
         or middle_name like '%santos%' 
         or gender like '%santos%' 
         or life_status like '%santos%' 
         or lds_number like '%santos%')
    and (birth_location like '%living%' 
         or death_location like '%living%' 
         or cause_death like '%living%' 
         or ethnicity like '%living%')
    and (birth_location like '%santos%' 
         or death_location like '%santos%' 
         or cause_death like '%santos%' 
         or ethnicity like '%santos%')

But if user inputs search term as Asian, ABCd then it does not give records as cause_death like %ABCd% and ethnicity like %Asian% condition does not match
So I want to write and condition in main table and or condition in all child tables as there are more than 10 child tables.
I have written the SQL query using codeigniter
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name, p.middle_name, p.gender, p.life_status');
$this->db->from("profiles p");
$this->db->join("vital v", "v.profile_id = p.id", "left");
$this->db->where('p.status', 'active');
if (!empty($data['search-term']) && !empty(array_filter($search_term_arr))) {
    foreach (array_filter($search_term_arr) as $term) {
        $this->db->group_start();
        $this->db->or_like("p.first_name", $term);
        $this->db->or_like("p.last_name", $term);
        $this->db->or_like("p.middle_name", $term);
        $this->db->or_like("p.gender", $term);
        $this->db->or_like("p.life_status", $term);
        $this->db->or_like("p.lds_number", $term);
        $this->db->or_like("v.birth_location", $term);
        $this->db->or_like("v.death_location", $term);
        $this->db->or_like("v.cause_death", $term);
        $this->db->or_like("v.ethnicity", $term);
        $this->db->group_end();
    }
}

but the query should be
select * 
from profiles p
left join vital v on v.profile_id = p.id
where 
(first_name like '%Asian%' or middle_name like '%Asian%' or gender like '%Asian%' or life_status like '%Asian%' or lds_number like '%Asian%' )
AND
(first_name like '%ABCd%' or middle_name like '%ABCd%' or gender like '%ABCd%' or life_status like '%ABCd%' or lds_number like '%ABCd%' )
AND
(
(birth_location like '%Asian%' or death_location like '%Asian%' or cause_death like '%Asian%' or ethnicity like '%Asian%')
OR
(birth_location like '%ABCd%' or death_location like '%ABCd%' or cause_death like '%ABCd%' or ethnicity like '%ABCd%')
)

Multiple joins will be there as there are more child tables.
I tried to write a stored procedure also, but I am not that expert in writing stored procedures.
Any help would be much more appreciated.
Thanks.
